# Can someone help me "find a process" in App Console .NET Core 3.1 project in order to run it on Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio-2019, .net-6.0, .net-core-3.1, c#-8.0

I have a very annoying problem that I haven't been able to solve for days. I was following some YouTube video lectures on C# .NET Core 3.1 and I was planning to create a new project on Visual Studio 2019, specifically Console Application in .NET Core 3.1. I created the project and after writing some code I could not start the program because [the "process" is not connected and does not let me debug it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ra9b.png). So far, one thing I have figured out is that Visual Studio only makes me debug projects in .NET Framework, where it can link the process, unfortunately that I don't want to use this version because it doesn't include all the new C# features that I would like to learn to be a good programmer. I would like to understand why this happens.

I have tried installing all the Visual Studio components but the problem persists. I gave up and tried using newer versions such as .NET 6.0 and 7.0 but these also do not work. I have also tried uninstalling and reinstalling it many times but nothing changes. What I wanted was a working project that I can compile and run.

Comment: .NET Core 3.1 is pretty old, and current VS is 2022. You could start off using Project>New and choose a .NET Console template (not the empty one), then try debugging without changing anything.  Don't worry about .net core or not for the moment, the thing first is getting used to how VS works.  If you really, really want .NET Core, it's probably best to start with VS Code. The [intro here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tutorials/with-visual-studio-code?pivots=dotnet-7-0) should get you going

Comment: Looks like you forgot to create a project.  Get started with File > New > Project.

Comment: Have you solved this issue? Just installed VS2019 to work on some legacy stuff and it does not work propeply just like you are describing.